# What would be the best way to persistently store HTTP responses for use in a web scraping application

Tags: python, mongodb, couchdb, distributed-caching

I'm looking for a key/value store in python that would be suitable for holding (and caching) HTTP responses (content, HTTP headers, timestamp) keyed by request URL. The application is a web scraping engine, where several sites are queried on a regular basis. A set of routines then analyses the scraped data.

The options I've investigated so far include:

- python shelve module (fast but data can't be distributed, write by single process only)
- mongodb (relatively fast, so far the best fit for what I am looking for)
- couchdb (too slow for this application)
- memcached (not suitable because the store is not persistent, and cached data can't be 
  replicated, correct me if I am wrong)

Some performance results using real scraped data:

```
python shelve:           3500 reads/second
couchdb (couchdbkit):      33 reads/second
mongodb (pymongo):       2300 reads/second
redis:                   1200 reads/second
```

Comment: Have you tried [redis](http://redis.io/)?

Comment: If you've considered memcached or redis, you should explain why they're not in the running. If you haven't looked in that direction yet, go check them out.

Comment: MongoDB is fast but given their nature memcached and to a lesser extent Redis should be faster. CouchDB seems like a suboptimal fit at best for this (each query is basically an m/r)

Comment: How do you store the URL in mongodb? If that is you key, you should index it, but indexing long strings might be slow, or not work at all if they are too long. Do you need to be able to enumerate the keys or would hashing be an option?

Comment: I haven't added memcached because I am looking for a persistent and distributed store, which means the store should survive a reboot without loosing any data, and cached entries on one node should be replicated to other nodes.

Comment: In mongodb, since the URL is the natural primary immutable and unique key, I've stored it in the _id field, which is automatically indexed.

Comment: I think you should test writes/second also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a capped collection in mongodb. Each entry holds the url (primary key), content and headers. Since capped collections doesn't allow removal, the content is set to Null to indicate a cached entry has been removed.